# AngularJS CSV File Download from API

Tags: angularjs, download, angular-ui-router, angular-resource, ngresource

I have an admin control panel where admin users can set a few options and then click a button to run a report. The report should return a CSV file download prompt to the user.

I am using `ui-router` and `$resource` services. The response headers/mime type are set correctly, but the CSV file is returned as text (no file download initiated) by the `$resource` handler.

I tried creating the download link directly, by forming a querystring from the `$scope`, but unfortunately my API's authentication scheme uses a custom HTTP header token and it's not possible to send that to the API (which is also on another subdomain) via an anchor tag, such as this one:

```
<a href="http://example.com/admin/report/csv?usertype=1&days=5">Run</a>
```

Is there a way to initiate a file download prompt using an XHR request (with custom header)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm using a custom header token so downloading the report via a simple link is impossible; the request has to be made via `XHR`. My two-part solution:

1. Returned the CSV data from the API directly as text, removing file `attachment` headers. This is the correct solution, anyway, because it keeps the REST JSON API unconcerned with file downloads, which are a browser concept.
2. Wrapped the API response data in a `Blob`, and then used https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js to initiate a file download.

A drawback is this requires IE10+, but that is okay in my case.

Comment: that seems reasonable, but do you have a fiddle or gist as an example? or can you update the answer with a script? thanks

Comment: Thanks Harper for your response. PM, please find below a bit of code following Harper post that works like a charm!

in view:
<a ng-click="exportToCsv()">

in controller, assuming the rest service returns an object with member called data which contains the csv raw data:
$scope.exportToCsv = function () {
     ReportAction.runFullReport($scope.filterCriteria).$promise.then(function (result) {
            var blob = new Blob([result.data], { type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8" });
            saveAs(blob, "report.csv");
        }), function() {
            console.log('error');
        };
    };